# VS 2013 Opening SSIS Solution with multiple projects that have protection level set

Tags: sql, ssis, visual-studio-2013

We are in the process of converting all of our old SQL 2008 SSIS packages to VS 2013/SQL 2014.  I've done the conversion process in VS 2013 and also started the conversion of Package Deployment to Project Deployment.  We currently use Encrypt All With Password as a protection level in the packages.  However, I now notice that one the ones I've converted to Project Deployment that when I open the solution each of those projects asks me for the password even though i haven't started any work in those projects.  This is different than the remaining packages I have not converted where it is not asking me for the password yet.  With well over 30 projects in the solution, I can't see having to type in 30 passwords for all the projects when I know I'm only going to be working on one.

Is there a setting that I am missing?  Or a workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to this is to disconnect your network connection, then open solution/projects. Then go back online. This may be faster if you have several projects.

You'll just have to enter the password for the package/project you're working on.  On a related note, once you have the solution open you can "Work Offline" under the SSIS menu to open a package and skip validation. This is useful for very large packages where SSIS might normally take a long time to validate everything in the package.

I would also like to hear the non-workaround answer to this question, if one exists.